# Read more button that rotate on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am currently working on a site and I need to have a "frequently asked questions" section. I designed it simply with a question, an icon and when you click on the div of that question, the answer appears.

I managed to make the answer appear without too much trouble but I am missing one last element, the rotation of the "+" icon which will become an "x".

I can't manage to rotate and animate this icon, I tried several ways but nothing works.
**I'm really a beginner in development especially if it touches the javascript.**

I am open to any advice and tips to help me, thanks in advance <3

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".show_hide").on("click", function () {
      $(this).next('.content').slideToggle(200);});
});
```

```css
body{
font-family:helvetica}

.show_hide{
cursor:pointer;}

#text{
display:none;}

.btn-container{
  margin: auto;}

#icon{
border-radius:50%;
border:1px solid black;
padding:5px;
float:right;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>


<section id="faq">
  <h2> Multiple questions</h2>
  
<hr>
<div class="show_hide" data-content="toggle-text">
  <big>This is a question ?</big>
  <i id="icon"class="fas fa-plus"></i>
</div>  

<div class="content">This is an answer.<br>This is an answer.<br>This is an answer.</div>

<hr>

<div class="show_hide" data-content="toggle-text">
  <big>This is a question ?</big>
  <i id="icon"class="fas fa-plus"></i>
</div>  

<div class="content">This is an answer.<br>This is an answer.<br>This is an answer. </div>
<hr>
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50016410/css-plus-to-close-button) work for you? They use `transform` and `rotate`.

Comment: Please confirm me , You want the + icon to rotate at 45 degree and show as X .

Comment: First, there should be unique `id` in a document, change the `id="icon"` into `class="icon"` and adjust css property name.

Comment: Java has nothing to do with JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `toggleClass()` inside the click event in JS file; then make a `active` class (or any other name you pick) inside CSS file where this class makes its content rotate by 45 degree via `transform: rotate(45deg)`.

Also, make sure all the `id` names are unique within a [single HTML document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Type_Class_and_ID_Selectors#id_selectors). In your case, I think it's better to change the `id="icon"` into `"class="icon"` as this is what `class` suppose to be.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".show_hide").on("click", function () {
      $(this).find('.icon').toggleClass('active');
      $(this).next('.content').slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

```css
body{
font-family:helvetica}

.show_hide{
cursor:pointer;}

#text{
display:none;}

.btn-container{
  margin: auto;}

.icon{
border-radius:50%;
border:1px solid black;
padding:5px;
float:right;}

.icon.active {
   transform: rotate(45deg)
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>


<section id="faq">
  <h2> Multiple questions</h2>
  
<hr>
<div class="show_hide" data-content="toggle-text">
  <big>This is a question ?</big>
  <i class="icon fas fa-plus"></i>
</div>  

<div class="content">This is an answer.<br>This is an answer.<br>This is an answer.</div>

<hr>

<div class="show_hide" data-content="toggle-text">
  <big>This is a question ?</big>
  <i class="icon fas fa-plus"></i>
</div>  

<div class="content">This is an answer.<br>This is an answer.<br>This is an answer. </div>
<hr>
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use the fa-rotate-* and fa-flip-* classes when you reference an icon.

```
 <i id="icon"class="fas fa-plus fa-rotate-90"></i>
```